# Свойства объектов в JS

Tags: javascript

В процессе изучения языка возник вопрос:
при помощи

```js
for (let key in obj){
alert([key]);
}
```

я могу посмотреть ключи в объекте.
Есть ли какой-либо способ аналогично вызывать их свойства подряд?
(заранее извиняюсь за глупость вопроса)

Comment: "аналогично вызывать их свойства подряд" - ??

Comment: под "аналогично вызвать свойства подряд" имеется в виду то, что если вызвать [key] в выше описанном способе, то выводятся все ключи в объекте подряд. мне же нужно вызвать их свойства без записи объект.ключ

Comment: Я ничего не понял. У Вас `obj` не пропущено в `[key]`?

Comment: console.log(obg[key]) так вроде

Comment: если я пропишу этот код:
let object = {
    smth: "свойство",
    yes: "еще одно свойство"
}
for (let key in object) {
   alert ([key])
}
то мне выведет smth и yes
имеется в виду вместо этого вывести подряд свойства ключей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот еще несколько вариантов получения данных из объекта.
Подробнее можно почитать на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Nick',
  age: 21,
  city: 'Moscow',
  adress: 'Pushkinskaya',
  appartments: 30
}

console.log(Object.keys(obj)) // => ключи объекта
console.log(Object.entries(obj)) // => пара ключ-значение объекта
console.log(Object.values(obj)) // => значения ключей объекта
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как по мне, данный вариант более лаконичен, т. к. не использует for.

Comment: Да, плюс если через цикл for...in перебирать, то так же перебираются и цепочки прототипов, [почитайте об этом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), полезно знать :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let obj = {
  smth: "свойство",
  yes: "еще одно свойство"
};
for (let key in obj) {
  console.log(key, "-", obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ. Извиняюсь за неточную формулировку вопроса.